# Swift Combine - delaying a publisher

Tags: swift, delay, publish-subscribe, combine

**TL;DR**

I want to delay a publication, but can't figure out how to, er, combine the parts

**In Brief**

I have a `Publisher`

```swift
let generator = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
```

and want somehow to use the modifier

```swift
.delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
```

so that when I call

```swift
generator.send(true)
```

the message is sent two seconds after the call to `send()`

Looking at the docs for [`Publishers.Delay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/delay) made the type error more clear, but doesn't help me to find the right way to hook things up.

**Code**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

// Exists just to subscribe.
struct ContainedView : View {
    private let publisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>
    init(_ publisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> = Just(false).dropFirst().eraseToAnyPublisher()) {
        self.publisher = publisher
    }
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().onReceive(publisher) { _ in print("Got it") }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let generator = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
                 // .delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                 // Putting it here doesn't work either.

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Tap") {

                // Does not compile
                self.generator.delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main).send(true)
                // Value of type 'Publishers.Delay<PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>, RunLoop>' has no member 'send'
                // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/delay

                // Does not compile
                self.generator.send(true).delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                // Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'delay'

                // Just a broken-up version of the first try.
                let delayed = self.generator.delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                delayed.send(true)

                // This, of course, builds and works.
                self.generator.send(true)
                print("Sent it")
            }

            ContainedView(generator.eraseToAnyPublisher())
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

`.delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)` is likely exactly what you need, but it'll be key to see how you're subscribing to fully understand the issue. Delay doesn't delay the sending of the value when using `send()` with a subject - that's a link for imperative code and sends the data whenever `send` is invoked, typically against some already existing subscription.

While you have a subscriber in the first bit of code, there isn't one with the subject to pin these together.

For example, if you updated:

`Just(false).dropFirst().eraseToAnyPublisher()`

to

`Just(false).dropFirst().eraseToAnyPublisher().delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)`

Then the print statement should trigger ~2 second after the the init() was invoked. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish here, using a closure trigger such as [`onAppear`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear) might make a lot more sense, having that call the `subject.send()`, which you can then delay as you like in the publisher chain that happens before whatever subscribes to it.

Comment: Thank you @heckj, I do feel, every time I use `send()` that I am being too imperative and if-this-then-that, instead of state-based, live-in-the-now.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the debounce property of a publisher to delay the publishing.

```swift
$yourProperty
    .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
let generator = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
let generated = generator.delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main).sink { value in
    print(value.description + " " + Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.description)
}
print(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.description)
generator.send(true)
generator.send(false)
```

#### output

```
641453284.840604
true 641453286.841731
false 641453286.847715
```